# Create a 2d array from an ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have an  ArrayList and I want to create a method that will turn it into a 2d array, int[][]. 
This new 2d array will represent a matrix and it has to be square, so for example if I use [8, 2, 3, 0] the ressult will be {8,2}
                                                  {3,0}

```
public static int[][] convertIntegers(ArrayList<Integer> integers){
        int m = (int) Math.sqrt(integers.size());
        int[][] ret = new int[m][m];

        int cont = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<m+1 ; i++)
       {
           for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
           {
               cont = cont + 1;
               ret[i][j] = integers.get(cont);
               ;
           }
       }
       return ret;}
```

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Edit your question and add the code. You should also state your problem more clearly than simple saying it doesn't work.

Comment: Estás imprimiendo solo el valor [0][0] de la matriz. Pero pareciera que si está bien el código.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña The primary language here is English. Anything else doesn't really fly here.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is almost ok, except for some *off-by-one* errors:

- You need to increment `cont` after the `integers.get` call, *not* before. If you increment before, then the first element of the list will be skipped. An easy way to fix that is to move the incrementing inside the inner loop, counting it together with `j`.
- The outer loop should go until `i < m` instead of `i < m + 1`

With the errors fixed:

```
for (int i = 0, cont = 0; i < m; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++, cont++) {
    ret[i][j] = integers.get(cont);
  }
}
```

Btw, another way is without using `cont` at all,
calculating the correct position using `i`, `j` and `m`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    ret[i][j] = integers.get(i * m + j);
  }
}
```